# how to add fade in and fade out

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am stuck with my project. 
I need to add to the code below fade-in and fade-out effect by using javascript and css only. please help me. 
I created this function to store all the data in the local storage and when I am clicking on the save button I want the note to be added with fade in effect. when I am deleting the note I want it to be deleted in fade out. only the note I am adding or deleting will be added or removed with the effect

this is the function to add the note:

```js
function saveIt() {   
    var content = document.getElementById("content").value;
    var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
    var time = document.getElementById("time").value;
    var id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);  //creating random id number.

    var note = { id: id, content: content, date: date, time: time };
    notesArray.push(note);

    localStorage.myList = JSON.stringify(notesArray);
    notesNewArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.myList);

    for (var i = 0; i < notesNewArray.length; i++) {
         theId = notesArray[i].id; 
        var output = "<div id='justFade'>" + "<div class='main col-xm-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3'>" + "<div class='note-bg'>" + "<div id='" + theId + "'" + "onclick='deleteNote(this.id)'>" + "<p id='hide-delete' class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle'></p>" + "</div>" + "<div class='noteContent'>" + notesNewArray[i].content + "</div>" + "<div class='noteDate'>" + notesNewArray[i].date + "</div>" + "<div>" + notesNewArray[i].time + "</div>" + "</div>" + "</div>" + "</div>";        
    }

    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += output;
    
    
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = ""; //to hide the message for the empty note. 
    document.getElementById("msgDate").innerHTML = "";   //to hide the message for the empty or wrong date. 
    document.getElementById("msgTime").innerHTML = "";   //to hide the message for the empty or wrong date.  
    document.forms['myNotes'].reset(); //reseting the form on saving.
    
    
    function deleteNote(clickedId) {
    var myList = localStorage.myList;
    notesArray = JSON.parse(myList);
    for (var i = 0; i < notesArray.length; i++) {
        if (notesArray[i].id == clickedId) {
            notesArray.splice(i, 1); // searching for the same ID number that the user clicked on and deleting it.
        }
        localStorage.myList = JSON.stringify(notesArray);
        notesNewArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.myList);        

        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "";
        getIt(); // calling again to the notes from the local storage.     
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>My Project</title>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower" rel="stylesheet">
        

        

    </head>
     <body id="init">

         <div class="center">
            <img src="img/title.png"  class="img-center" alt="My Task Board" width="876" height="225">          
        </div>

         <div class="container-fluid">             
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
                 <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <form id="myNotes" name="myNotes">
                        <div class="form-group">
                             <textarea rows="8" name="myContent" cols="100" class="form-control" id="content" placeholder="type your note here..." required></textarea><br>                            
                             <div><input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" required></div>
                             <div><input type="time" class="form-control" id="time" required></div>
                             <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="save" value="save">
                             <div id="msg"></div>
                            <div id="msgDate"></div>
                            <div id="msgTime"></div>
                        </div>                                      
                    </form>
                 </div>                    
                 <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
             </div>
         </div>
        <div id="results" class="singleNote"></div>
        <script src="js/myscript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

thank you.

Comment: You're already using jQuery according to your HTML markup, why not just use `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`?

Comment: Hi, I am not using jQuery.... can you help me please solve it by using JS only?

Comment: @IdanDamti Check my answer below please. Working examples of `fade in` and `fade out` with `plain javascript`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to solve this problem.  For any element that requires to fade in or out you can do this...

```
$("#div1").fadeIn();
$("#div1").fadeOut();
```

Here is a link that explains...
[Jquery fade in and out](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp)

Comment: Hi, I can't use jQuery... can you help me doing it with JS only?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make two `async` functions `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` and a function to return a `promise`.

With `async` you are solving the function `asynchronously` meaning other code can continue executing and doesn't have to wait for the return of a priorly called function to start it's execution. Because of this they appear to fade in and out at the same time even though they are called by 4 different lines of code.

Here is a quick example of `fade in` and `fade out` done in plain javascript:
(Run the snippet at the bottom of the code)

```js
function sleep(ms)
{
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function fadeIn(elmnt)
{
  for(var i=0; i<101; i++)
  {
    document.getElementById(elmnt).style.opacity = i/100;
    await sleep(20);     // Play with the sleep time to suit your needs, in miliseconds
  }
}


async function fadeOut(elmnt)
{
  for(var i=100; i > -1; i--)
  {
    document.getElementById(elmnt).style.opacity = i/100;
    await sleep(20);
  }
}

// Simply call the functions anywhere you want like this
fadeIn('fade_1');
fadeIn('fade_2');

fadeOut('fade_3');
fadeOut('fade_4');
```

```css
.opacityZero
{
  opacity:0;
}


.opacityOne
{
  opacity:1;
}

.firstDiv
{
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  width:97%;
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding:5px;
}

.secondDiv
{
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  width:98%;
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding:5px;
}

.container
{
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  width:95%;
  margin-top:20px;
  border:1px solid #09f;
  padding:10px;
}

h3
{
  font-family:calibri;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<h3>Fade in effect</h3>

<div id="fade_1" class="firstDiv opacityZero">hi</div>

<div class="container">
  <span id="fade_2" class="secondDiv opacityZero">hi</span>
</div>

<h3 style="margin:20px 0 0;">Fade out effect</h3>

<div id="fade_3" class="firstDiv opacityOne">hi</div>

<div class="container">
  <span id="fade_4" class="secondDiv opacityOne">hi</span>
</div>
```